# Keep divs from stacking when browser resized

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

So I have a website that when it is resized the divs start to stack. I have been unable to figure out why as I am using min-width on the container.

Here is how the divs are laid out:

```
<div id="content">

<div id="leftColumn">
</div>

<div="content">
</div>

</div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
#container {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 99%;
min-width: 700px;
height: 100%;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
z-index: 0;
display: inline-block;
white-space: nowrap;
}

#leftColumn {
width: 20%;
min-width: 200px;
height: 100%;
background-color: #2196f3;
color: white;
text-align: center;
float: left;
font-size: 100%;
display: inline;
}

#content {
text-align: center;
left: 0%;
height: 100%;
width: 80%;
min-width: 498px;
background-color: white;
float: left;
display: inline;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are missing an id or class for the second "content" div in the code above. Also are you trying to have all these items display on one line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you be opposed to using inline-block instead of floats? Like [This:](http://jsfiddle.net/gv7as4nv/)

HTML

```
<div id="container">
<div id="leftColumn">leftcolumn</div>
<div id="content">content</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
z-index: 0;
display: inline-block;
white-space: nowrap;
}
#leftColumn {
min-width:200px;
height: 100%;
background-color: #2196f3;
color: white;
text-align: center;
display:inline-block;
font-size: 100%;
}
#content {
text-align: center;
min-width:200px;
width:80%;
height: 100%;
background-color: white;
display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your wrote

```html
<div="content"></div>
```

this. You missed ID declaration. It should be

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```